# C# - How to prepend byte[] with ushort and send it over TCP

Tags: c#, c++, flatbuffers

I am using Flatbuffers with C++ and I prepend `uint16_t` enum infront of the flatbuffer message and I send it over TCP with Boost Asio. More for FlatBuffers you can check [here](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers).

Here is how I do it in C++:

```
enum ServerOpcode : uint16_t{
    SERVER_AUTH_CONNECTION_RESPONSE                    = 0x001,
    SERVER_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE                      = 0x002,
    SERVER_NUM_MSG_TYPES                               = 0x003,
};

void ConnectAuthserverCommand::SendLogin(tcp::socket &s, const flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder &builder) const {

    ClientOpcode opc = CLIENT_LOGIN_REQUEST;
    flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder2;

    auto email = builder2.CreateString("test@abv.bg");
    auto password = builder2.CreateString("test");
    auto clientHashStr = builder2.CreateString(clientHash);
    auto loginRequest = Vibranium::CreateLoginRequest(builder2, email, password, clientHashStr);
    builder2.FinishSizePrefixed(loginRequest);
    size_t size2 = builder2.GetSize();
    uint8_t *buf2 = builder2.GetBufferPointer();

    uint8_t *actualBuffer2 = new uint8_t[size2 + 2];
    actualBuffer2[1] = (opc >> 8);
    actualBuffer2[0] = (opc&0xFF);
    memcpy(actualBuffer2 + 2, buf2, size2);

    boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(actualBuffer2,size2 + 2));
}
```

I know that `uint16_t` is exactly 2 bytes and that is why i add +2.

Okay than. I would like to do same thing but in `C#` as well and send it over TCP.

Here is the `ushort` enum because I checked that `ushort` in C# is the equivalent of `uint16_t` in C++. I would like to prepend with exactly 2 bytes infront of my `byte[]`.

```
public enum ServerOpcode : ushort
{
    SERVER_AUTH_CONNECTION_RESPONSE                    = 0x001,
    SERVER_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE                      = 0x002,
    SERVER_NUM_MSG_TYPES                               = 0x003,

}
```

So as I said I would like to prepend a Flatbuffers packet with ushort enum and here I tried something like this:

```
    public void Send(FlatBufferBuilder builder, ClientOpcode opcode)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[builder.SizedByteArray().Length + 2];
        buffer[0] = (byte)((ushort)opcode / 0x0100);
        buffer[1] = (byte)opcode;
        Array.Copy(builder.SizedByteArray(), 0, buffer, 2, builder.SizedByteArray().Length);
        
        if (buffer.Length > MaxMessageSize)
        {
            Logger.LogError("Client.Send: message too big: " + buffer.Length + ". Limit: " + MaxMessageSize);
            return;
        }

        if (Connected)
        {
            // respect max message size to avoid allocation attacks.
            if (buffer.Length <= MaxMessageSize)
            {
                // add to send queue and return immediately.
                // calling Send here would be blocking (sometimes for long times
                // if other side lags or wire was disconnected)
                sendQueue.Enqueue(buffer);
                sendPending.Set(); // interrupt SendThread WaitOne()
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.LogWarning("Client.Send: not connected!");
        }
    }
```

If you would like to know more for how the packet is send over TCP check our [Telepathy TCP](https://github.com/vis2k/Telepathy/blob/master/Telepathy/Client.cs)

My C# `Send` function seems to not prepend correctly the enum code. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Let me show you how I call my C# `Send` function:

```
ClientOpcode clientOpcode = ClientOpcode.CLIENT_LOGIN_REQUEST;
var builder = new FlatBuffers.FlatBufferBuilder(1);
var email = builder.CreateString("test@abv.bg");
var password = builder.CreateString("test");
var loginRequest = LoginRequest.CreateLoginRequest(builder, email, password);
LoginRequest.FinishSizePrefixedLoginRequestBuffer(builder,loginRequest);

Send(builder, clientOpcode);
```

Do you see where is my mistake ?

Comment: You reversed the byte order for some reason.

Comment: Hey @HansPassant Any suggestion how to fix ?Can you form up and answer with solution ?

Comment: Just swap the buffer[0] and [1] assignments.  I can't tell if it is a typo or intentional, the C++ code is oddly reversed.  Might have been a bug fix, look through the source control history.

Comment: Please don't translate C++ `>>8` to `/ 0x0100`... C# has bit-shifting operators too.

Comment: @BenVoigt how do you suggest it to be ?

Comment: `>>8` just like it was in C++

Comment: @BenVoigt can you please make a complete answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: It's not a complete answer.  Hans's comment on the fact that you changed the byte indexing is likely to be your real problem.  My comment was more about readability of the code... when your intention is a bit shift, use the bit shift operator.  Introducing division will make future readers of the code have to analyze it and find out that its effect is a bit shift.

Comment: @BenVoigt I understand. However can you form up an answer with changes you think will solve the question ? I am still nowhere solving this issue. Help will me much appreciated!

Comment: Might I suggest hexdumping the final buffer from both C++ and C# so you can compare the output?  (You could write the buffer to a binary file, for example `File.WriteAllBytes()` in C#, and use an external hexdump tool)

Comment: @BenVoigt what program I need to make that hexdumping ?

Comment: @BenVoigt i've managed to fetch some output can you please check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805086/c-sharp-cant-make-same-tcp-message-structure-on-c-sharp-client-as-it-was-on-c

Comment: @Venelin: Looks like you are capturing the exact data needed to solve this.  Now please use `-x` option to ngrep to print it out in hex.